# how to run 'free -m' every minute & add to current page (php only)

Tags: php, javascript

I need to

- **run** 'free -m' every minute
- and then **add** the result to the previous results

So the script is going to run only of I call the free.php from my browser. I want to use **php 5.3** + **javascript/AJAX** + **html** only (=no cron, jQuery etc)

Comment: Is your PHP/Apache user allowed to get that info in the first place? (just to prevent future disappointment)

Comment: yes I've just tried and I get displayed in browser what I want. What I do not know how to add new line of result to the existing page

Comment: You can't do that without either keeping the script running and performing output every 60 seconds, or using an ajax request to fetch the data.  All scripts will time out eventually; an ajax request is among the most simple and straight-forward thing you could possibly do to accomplish this.  The most simple thing would be a cron job.  Why have you excluded both of these simple things?

Comment: @Charles: I think I didn't exclude AJAX. In my eyes AJAX is bit more than javascript

Comment: @Charles he's not excluding Ajax

Comment: Ah, the post has been edited.  Though you're still excluding jQuery, which tends to be the tool of choice around here for ajax requests.

Comment: I added AJAX as an option to make things clearer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set_time_limit(0);

$results = array();

while (TRUE) {

   system('free -m', $result);

   $results[] = $result;

   sleep(60);

}
```

This kind thing would work great as a cron, however.

Comment: cool but how do I sent new result to the browser? without much of refreshing if possible

Comment: Maybe using set_time_limit(0); in the beginning?

Comment: @huff: why did you deleted you answer? I do like it ... it works great... but it runs every millisecond or so :-) how can I format the output? or better how can I extract only one value from the output?

Comment: @huff Whoops, I may need that :)

Comment: @Radek: Yeah, I forgot to sleep()! I deleted my answer because I thought it didn't add much to this answer... and wasn't sure that you wanted to directly output the results (passthru instead of system/exec, then flush).

Comment: @huff: I like your solution.I used it.But it it is not so reliable,it times out...Maybe the other solution will be better.

Answer (score 2):

I know you don't want to use jQuery here, but it's just one tool available.  You can totally replace it with whatever ajax library you prefer.

The critical thing is going to be managing a [Javascript timer](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

```
// Here's the function that will be run.
    function get_free_mem() {
        $.get('/free_mem.php', {}, function(data){
        // data contains the HTML output from the script.
        // '#somewhere' is the HTML element that you want the
        // output of the script appended to.
            $('#somewhere').append(data);
        }, 'html');
    }
// And here's how we'll run it.
    var timer = setInterval(get_free_mem, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds
```

And here's `free_mem.php`:

```
<pre><?php passthru('free -m'); ?></pre>
```

Every 60 seconds, the `get_free_mem` function will fire, which will request the PHP script and append the output to an HTML element on the page.

(This code is untested.)

---

(Yes, I realize that the `setInterval` thing can backfire and cause uneven update timing if the called script takes a while to return, and that using `setTimeout` instead and re-triggering it on ajax completion is better practice, but I believe that the called script is simple enough that this shouldn't be too much of a problem here.)